# multiple files as attachment from a form and send a email

Tags: php, forms, email, attachment

Following is the code I am using to send multiple files as attachment in a mail, tested it in local environment, the attachments were reaching the mail box but as empty files, and in live environment, result is mail could not be sent, though files get saved in the upload folder on the server...a newbie in php so please can anyone help what am I doing wrong..??
In local environment i was using this code $server_file = "/localhost:81/xyz/uploads/$path_parts[basename]"; in place what is mentioned down there under move this file to the server

```
    <?php

     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //did files get sent
        if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

    //define allowed extensions
        $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt");
        $files = array();
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];

    //loop through all the files
        foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file){
    //define some variables
        $file_name= $file['name'];
        $temp_name= $file['tmp_name'];
    //check if this file type is allowed
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
            die("extension not allowed");
        }
    //move this file to the server
        $server_file = "/home/public_html/xyz.com/uploads/$path_parts[basename]";
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$server_file);
    //add this file to array of files
        array_push($files,$server_file);
        }

    //define some mail variables
        $to = "info@xyz.com";
        $from = "From: $username<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject = "Photo attachment of . $name .";
        $msg = "Images of $username, $email";
        $headers = "From: $from";
    //define our boundary
        $semi_rand =  md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    //tell the header about the boundary
        $headers .= "nMIME-Version:1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
        $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    //part1: define the plain text email
        $message = "\n\n--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $message .="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
        $message .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n". $msg ."\n\n";
        $message .="--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    //part2: loop and define mail attachments
        foreach($files as $file){
        $aFile = fopen($file,"rb");
        $data = fread($aFile,filesize($file));
        fclose($aFile);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .="Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n";
        $message .= " name=\"$files\"\n";
        $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n";
        $message .= " filename=\"$files\"\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        }
    //send the email
        $ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $from);
        if($ok){
            header("Location: thank-your.php");
            }
            else{
            echo"<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";
        }
        die();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe be carefull to the weight of your attachments, for example, GMail allows you less than 15Mb or 20Mb of attachment

Comment: @ji_bay_...I tried with lowest file sizes, but still in local environment, there are empty files named array and in live environment, 'mail could not be sent' is the result.

Comment: Somehow the status of the above code has changed to this error...Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\glambuds\attach.php on line 59 n& 61...line no 59 is this one..  $message .= " name=\"$files\"\n";....can sumone help please..thanks in advance